# Manage data on my hosting server

Tags: database, web, hosting, backend, web-hosting

first of all sorry if this question is stupid. I'm building a website from scratch and I don't want to use a CMS. I'm doing well with all, unless that I don't know how to manage the backend data. It's suposed to make a direct connection to the database, for example, to create a new post on the blog page? Or should I implement a software in some language that connects to the database and manages all the posts that I post?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question to ask and if you're designing something on your own you should do what works for you.  There are multiple solutions to the question you're asking but what fits you is the right answer.  Stack is mostly questions for problems that have an actual example or something happening.  Your asking an architectural question which isn't a bad thing just a very broad question to ask.  Try Googling storing Blog posts.  I assume this is what you want to do...

Some options:
Cloud based Architecture - Azure, Amazon Web Services (AWS) pay as you grow.
MongoDB, PostGres, SQL databases, Oracle, use a database that fits your code base.
Maybe spend some time learning a Full Stack Web Development cycle and what it takes to achieve.  Some stacks are:
M.E.A.N. - MongoDB database, Express (Node Package) web server, Angular (1.. to 5) Web Development, Nodejs multiple uses
L.A.M.P. - Linux operating system, APACHE web server, MySQL (Database), PHP web development
.NET Stack or ASP.NET C# For your backend, use jQuery, SQL, Angular/React.

As you can see a lot to look at or learn.  No simple answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, and sorry for my bad english, it did not explained me well! I use XAMPP stack! I'm okay with frontend/backend but what I would like to know it's for example, if I should connect directly from my pc to MariaDb in the hosting server(idk if it is the right way to say) and insert a new post in the post table, or if I should develop a software to insert my posts on the database. I know, at least I think I know that I can do it both ways, but I would like to know the normal and secure way to do it! Thanks again and sorry again if I had bad english!